# Adverbes en -ment basés sur un adverbe

Tags: adverbes

'Quasiment' est un adverbe en -ment basé sur l'adverbe 'quasi'. Existe-il d'autres adverbes sur cette construction ?

Answer (score 2):

En regardant une liste d'adverbes sur ce site http://aidenet.eu/grammaire20b.htm, j'ai trouvé

- «tard» et «tardivement»
- «bref» et «brièvement», la racine de ce dernier venant de «brief», ancienne forme de «bref» selon le Larousse : https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bri%c3%a8vement/11155?q=bri%c3%a8vement#11010

Je te laisse le soin de la lire plus attentivement pour repérer d'autres exemples. Elle est triée par ordre alphabétique, donc les mots qui t'intéressent doivent se suivre, ce qui simplifie la tâche.

Je pense aussi a «bon» et «bonnement» qui n'est pas dans la liste précédente.

Je suis conscient que ces exemples ne reprennent pas exactement la construction de la question, qui ajoute seulement «ment» à l'adverbe initial, mais ce sont des adverbes en «ment» basés sur un autre adverbe.

Answer (score 1):

En voilà d'autres :

- Ferme / fermement
- Juste / justement
- Même / mêmement
- Raide / raidement
- Vite / vitement

Answer (score 0):

Oui, il en existe au moins un;

- fin, finement      [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fin/33784)

Cependant, l'usage ne reflète pas celui de  « quasi » ; je ne crois pas que l'on trouve une autre combinaison que « fin prêt » et « finement prêt » ne serais pas employé ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finement+pr%C3%AAt&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)).